# Undefined is not an object -- LoginManager.LoginWithReadPermissions

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to implement FB Login in my app, but I get the following error when I click on login button.

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions')
> loginWithFacebook
> C:\Users\Sumanth's HP\Documents\React Native\Etcetera\src\components\LoginForm.js:22:9
> proxiedMethod

My LoginForm is this way:

```
import {AccessToken, LoginManager} from 'react-native-fbsdk';

export default class LoginForm extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

loginWithFacebook(){
    LoginManager
    .logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile','email'])
    .then((result) =>{
        if (result.isCancelled) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('The user cancelled the request'));
        }
        //console.log(`Login success with permissions: ${result.grantedPermissions.toString()}`);
        // get the access token
        return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    })
    .then(data =>{
        const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);      
            return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
    })
    .then((currentUser) => {
        console.log(`Facebook Login with user : ${JSON.stringify(currentUser.toJSON())}`);            
        this.props.rootNav.navigate('signup');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Facebook login fail with error: ${error}`);
    });
}


render(){
    
    return( 
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput 
                    style={styles.inputBox} 
                    placeholder='Email'
                    underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                />
                <TextInput 
                    style={styles.inputBox} 
                    placeholder='Password'
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                />
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonStyle}>
                        Login
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.thirdPartySignup}>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.thirdPartyButtonStyle}>
                            Google
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.loginWithFacebook}>
                        <Text style={styles.thirdPartyButtonStyle}>
                            Facebook
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.signup}>
                <Text style={styles.signupCont}>Don't have an account yet? </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.rootNav.navigate('signup')}>
                    <Text style={styles.signupButton}>Signup!  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            </View> 
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: try running `npm install react-native-fbsdk` again

Comment: @JojoNarte thanks for response. i tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Try manually installing the FBSDK.